# How to set an email address to mailto in html

Tags: php, html, mailto

This is my code:

```
<table>
            <tr><th>Enquiry ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th><th>Date</th><th>Message</th><th align="center">Respond</th></tr>
            <?php
                require_once('includes/dbh.inc.php');
                $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from enquiries");
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                    echo '<tr><td>'.$row["enquiry_id"].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row["author_f_name"].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row["author_l_name"].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row["author_email"].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row["author_phone"].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row["post_date"].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row["message"].'</td>';
                    echo '<td><a href="mailto:"><p style="color:red";>Reply</p></a></td></tr>';     
                }
            ?>
    </table>
```

I am fetching data to a table from database table, enquiries. If the user click on Reply link I want to get the email address according to enquiry_id near mailto:
How to do that?
Someone help me, Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply change the following line:

```
echo '<td><a href="mailto:"><p style="color:red";>Reply</p></a></td></tr>';
```

to:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"mailto:{$row['author_email']}\"><p style=\"color:red;\">Reply</p></a></td></tr>";
```